# BlockComposer.ShowText() doesnt have an option to draw underline text?

Tags: pdfclown

I'm using blockComposer.ShowText("foo") to build texts but how to do an underline?

I don't see enough examples on underline text, how do you all make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text decorations (underline, line-through, overline) haven't been supported yet: they are generally considered an ugly and discouraged typographic habit, so that even the PDF spec doesn't natively support them (it all ends up with cosmetic graphic lines placed somewhere near the text glyphs).

It's not that tough job to add them... I simply avoided them in abhorrence, but I fear there shall come the day when I am forced to deal with this ;) ... maybe in forthcoming 0.2.0 version?

Comment: Awww!  Alrighty!!  I'll learn to use Graphic drawing for that. I can see where you're coming from. Here we have word processor where title or few wording in sentences have underline, to make a point (or bold statement).  There's also a Signature followed by name and underline. Yea, it is inevitable down the road.